# how to solve parsing error in Robo3t for MongoDb?

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I'm new to MongoDB and Robo3T and I simply want to insert a new object into an existing database. I checked the Syntax for the insert command and googled for that error, but i didn't see any way to fix this, since to me it seems i made everything right.
The command I enter is:

```
db.Deponie.insert({
    "Name":"Deponie Müller",
    "Baumaterialien":
    {
        "name":"Papier",
        "PreisProTonne":2,
        "PreisProM3":3
    }
})
```

but I get an parsing error as a result for this query:

> Unable to parse JSON: Expecting ':', at (2, 7)

.

I don't know what I have to chance since on the official page it shows this syntax as well. It would be very nice if someone could help me with that..

Answer (score 0):

Try without the space on the first line like this:

db.Deponie.insert({"Name":"Deponie Müller",
        "Baumaterialien":
        {
            "name":"Papier",
            "PreisProTonne":2,
            "PreisProM3":3
        }
    })

Answer (score 0):

Noticed this errors few times, eventhough syntax looks good. Most of the times copying scripts from other sources this error will show up, I used to put it in a editor and convert the encoding to ANSI to see any weird characters in the scripts. Remove those or retype those lines used to solve my issue.